# Trying to upgrade Groovy app from 2.3.1 to 3.3.15, I am getting lots of errors like below. any help will be appriciated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grails, groovy

| Running application...
2022-10-11 17:19:04.189 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [splitseasontickets.main4.Application]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration

```
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:561)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:187)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:666)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:353)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at splitseasontickets.main4.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
- org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration

```
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.handleInvalidExcludes(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.checkExcludedClasses(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:552)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  | Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

I am using the below dependencies in gradle...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.15.1"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "splitseasontickets.main4"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime 'org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.2'
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
    runtime 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:3.4.7'
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb:1.1.2"
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.52.0'
    testRuntime 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.64.0'
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:4.5.0'
   // compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.1-beta2'
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client:6.1.9.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:3.0.13'
    //compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-web-common', version: '3.0.17'
   compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-core', version: '3.1.14'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    compile group: 'org.jmdware', name: 's3-bucket-recursor', version: '1.0.1'

    // compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-grape', version: '3.19.0'

    //compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.1.2'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.5.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.grails', name: 'grails-plugin-controllers', version: '3.3.16'



}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
    String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
    systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "geb.env", System.getProperty('geb.env')
    systemProperty "geb.build.reportsDir", reporting.file("geb/integrationTest")
    systemProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver')
    systemProperty "webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver')
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Comment: Please check how to write a question title: [ask]. Don't post phrases like "any help will be appreciated" there...

Answer (score 0):

```
maven { url "https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/"}
compile 'org.springframework:org.springframework.beans:2.5.6.SEC01'
```

Try with this